# How to type a string to end a integer Scanning process in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to use Scanner to scan any number of integer then get the average. Before I stop, I would like to type "END".

The code below has:
***Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException*** error. That is because I scan a string rather than int type.

How should I solve this problem?

Thanks

```
public static int scanaverage()
{
System.out.println("Enter any number, type 'END' to exit");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int total=0; 
int count = 0;

while (!(input.nextLine().equals("END")))
{
total += input.nextInt();
count += 1;
}
return total / count;
}
```

Comment: Use `input.nextLine()` to read the value as a String and then use `Integer.parseInt()` to convert String to int. use `equalsIgnoreCase()` check before  parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just scan the whole line and check if the line is a number like this

```
public static int scanaverage() {
    System.out.println("Enter any number, type 'END' to exit");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    String line;
    do {
        line = input.nextLine();
        try {
            total += Integer.parseInt(line); // Cast the number, if it does not succeed catch the exception.
            count += 1;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            if(!line.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) { // Wrong input
                System.out.println("Wrong input, input another number or end");
            }
        }
    } while (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("end"));
    return total / count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Exception is due to two read operation for getting one number, For Example
take input as

1

2

3

END

Debug:

while loop condition  `input.nextLine()` will fetch 1
then `input.nextInt()` will fetch 2
while loop condition  `input.nextLine()` will fetch 3
then `input.nextInt()` will fetch END --> This will throw InputMismatchException

Hope the bellow code will work, except the part that Any non int input will break the loop

```
public static int scanaverage()
{
System.out.println("Enter any number, type 'END' to exit");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int total=0; 
int count = 0;

while (input.hasNextInt()))
{
total += input.nextInt();
count += 1;
}
return total / count;
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't support the - *user should type "end"* part

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a try catch block as follows.

```
public static int scanaverage()
{
  System.out.println("Enter any number, type 'END' to exit");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int total=0; 
  int count = 0;

  while (!(input.nextLine().equals("END")))
  {
   try{
    total += input.nextInt();
    count += 1;
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){

    }
  }
  return total / count;
}
```

I haven't test it.